# iOS Facebook SDK v4: App Invite sends successfully to test users but not others

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

My app is live on the iOS app store and I've set up App Invites with the latest FB SDK (v4).

Everything must be set up correctly in terms of the App Link as the invite works with test users but not non-test users, a notification is received and the user is taken to the app store when they click on this.

Is there an extra setting on the Facebook side that needs switching on for this to work with regular users?

Comment: Are you sure the users have not disabled all App Invites?  Have them check "Manage apps" settings.  Also, I would recommend trying a few more accounts to make sure the problem is reproducible.  I recall seeing inconsistent behavior with Facebook App Requests that I never did get to the bottom of.

Comment: It is very strange, I've tested it again and some other users did receive the notification. It does seem to be inconsistent. Thanks though!